# Sending SMS text message from an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

How can I send an SMS message to a cellular phone number from an ASP.NET web site?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195624/sms-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 8):

If you know the service provider you can send an email to their phone, which is then converted into an sms message. For instance with Verizon Wireless phones it would be phonenumber@vtext.com

[Here](http://www.emrupdate.com/blogs/ducknet/archive/2008/11/30/how-to-send-email-text-messages-to-any-cell-phone-for-free-from-your-computer.aspx) is a list of popular US carriers and the email addresses they use.

If you don't you could try an SMS gateway service. I'm not sure of any because I have never tried.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an SMS service provider. They will have an API, such as a web service or some other url, which you will call to send the SMS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1) Get a contract with the network onto which you want to send SMS. 
it will probably be quite expensive if your not sending alot of messages. 
You will need a new contract with each network provider you want to use.

2) Use a sms service provider. 
Which one to use depends on where you live and what networks you want to send to. 
we use http://www.cellsynt.com/en/ simple and reliable.

You could ofcourse use some Mail2SMS provider, but then you need to know what network the number is on. In case of sending SMS to your friend that is an option but if there could be any other number your better of using option 2 until you send tons of messages then option 1 might be cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

As most people have already said you can use a service provider, you can also get a connection to a carrier's SMSC (unlikely) another option is using a GSM modem. They usually come with an API that will allow you to among other things send SMS messages.