# SMS Library in C#

Tags: c#, sms, gateway

I need to develop an application that sends SMS to the users that are interested to get the updates about the website.

I am looking for Library in C# which is useful to integrate with my application. The Library can be GSM Modem dependent or free service which i can make use of it.

Please can anyone suggest the library or SMS gateway which can be integrated with C# application.

Comment: Are you planning on setting up your own SMS gateway or just leasy one (The ladder is the easier choice) ? Oh, and which country are you in?

Comment: It can which ever is better. I am doing for USA.

Comment: psst...don't forget to mark the answer that worked for you. And if no answer worked, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380066/send-sms-c-net

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the System.Net.Mail functions to send mail to the email corresponding to the phone number?

e.g. 6566565656@vtext.com

(List of email domains here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/)

EDIT: even bigger list here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

EDIT 2:
Bigger list here, Wikipedia link no longer has as much information
http://www.ukrainecalling.com/email-to-text.aspx

Comment: The user can have the mobiles with any providers. It may be Virgin, T-Mobile, AT & T. I should be able to send SMS to the users with regardless of their providers. So i am waiting for a better solution to use a Library or Gateway.

Comment: 100 rep says you end up taking this route

Comment: You could always ask the user for the name of their carrier.  I believe this is why most places offering SMS services ask for it.

Comment: So frigging easy and useful.  brb spamming millions of numbers.

Comment: The list of SMS gateways has been moved to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_Email_or_Web_to_SMS

Answer (score 2):

Use [Gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/), this is a console application you can use it in any type of application, launch the application capture the output then process it, already i had done in my c# project. Gammu  has capablity to connecting to any type of gsm modem

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments, I'd say leasing a SMS gateway is the easier option. I don't have any experience with USA gateway providers, but from the ones I've worked with, I can say that they are all fairly simple. Most of good ones has .Net APIs ready for you, so you essentially just call SendSMS(string phonenumber, string message) on them. If they don't have any .Net APIs they ussually have webservices ready for you, which is a 1-click integration into Visual Studio.

A simple google search came up with quite a few providers :)

http://www.google.dk/search?hl=da&q=sms+gateway+usa&meta=&aq=f&oq=

Answer (score 0):

1. Sending SMS is no longer free, ofcourse all ISPs dont want their customers to get spammed heavily if it would be free !!
2. If you want to send sms from your website within your .net code, then you can try clickatell.com, because anyway on webserver you cant really connect a cellphone unless you can get a chance to get into datacenter and setup your own hardware.

Comment: The Client is ready to have the GSM Modem of their own, through which the application can send SMS. Are there any libraries that i can use to send through hardware(GSM Modem)

Comment: Most GSM modems have AT command sets that can send SMS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a lot of SMS messages then a gateway and a bundle deal is by far the cheapest way to go - you generally just send an email to the gateway with the users number in the subject line. If you want something more flexible (but not as cheap) then try  [Email to SMS](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/219-email-to-sms.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently use "mCore .Net Library 1.2" for this purposes. It's simple enough, but unfortunately not completely bug-free.

Answer (score 0):

Our team member has just posted a tutorial on how to send sms using c#.

```
// Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://isms.com.my/isms_send.php?un=" + username.Text + "&pwd=" + mypassword.Text + "&dstno=" + phonebox.Text + "&msg=" + msgbox.Text + "&type=1&sendid=60198899001");

// Create a new request to the above mentioned URL.
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);

// Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

string s_ResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

So if you are interested, just head over to http://www.isms.com.my/how-to-send-sms-c-sharp.php and you can also download the demo file for testing purposes. :)

Click [HERE](http://www.isms.com.my/download/isms-demo-project.zip) to download iSMS Demo Project

Comment: Could you please post the revelant part of the tutorial inside the answer instead of just add the link? Like I did? Thanks.