# Send SMS C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, sms

Is there any free gate way or a way that I can use  to send SMS from my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On popular wireless carriers you can just email the number. For example AT&T:

5555555555@att.net

Just find the appropriate email servers for the number, then append it to the end of the address. Hope this helps.

Comment: Would anyone here know how one would process such a message on the email server side? Obviously they don't have a mail box for every possible phone number.

Comment: Are you sure? Well maybe they have some kind of system that takes all emails sent that match a phone number, then forwards that message to the sms server? I'm not sure how sms works, so I could be wrong.

What do you mean process such a message on the email server side? You'll have to figure out regex patterns to match what service goes to a particular number, then append the appropriate address, or you'll have to try emailing to all of the services until you don't get an error.

Although, the first one is recommended for obvious reasons.

Comment: List Of Email-To-SMS Addresses

https://avtech.com/articles/138/list-of-email-to-sms-addresses/

Answer (score 4):

You can buy a GSM modem and use C# to send AT commands to it to send sms.

Comment: +1  If you are going to do real work with SMS, you need to have control over your process.  Using a gateway is fine if not mission critical, but you run into the problem of not knowing the correct carrier and the gateway can go away leaving you high and dry.  At least consider buying your own wireless modem.  They make them with multiple 4 to 6 SIM card slots too.

Answer (score 3):

there are no free SMS gateways. but they are not expesive. if you buy bulk packages prices are nice. just google "sms gateway" and pick any. they usually have webservice interface or other http interface that makes it easy to call from C#

Comment: Also, You can check with [sms integration using c#](https://www.springedge.com/csharp-aspnet-send-sms-gateway-integration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Most SMS systems have an email interface.  See http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/

The hard part is knowing who the cell provider is for your client.

Answer (score 0):

Each cell phone provider typically has email addresses that work as aliases for forwarding an email to SMS.  Since I believe you have the mobile numbers, if you know the carrier you can use their domain to simply create emails that get redirected to the mobile user's SMS text messages.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway is basically a service that you can call from your C# code and communicate with it over HTTP. This is why you can basically use any gateway, no matter if it is based on .NET or not. If you want to host a free one yourself, [here's one for Linux](http://www.kannel.org/).

And here's the WSDL for a service that says it can send SMS messages in the whole world. (Not tested):
http://www.webservicex.com/sendsmsworld.asmx?WSDL

Comment: I am damn sure this not work I tried already tried this

Comment: I tried the service to send SMS and didn't receive it. I'm currently in Brazil.