# phonenumber@operator.com - How do they do it?

Tags: email, sms

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380066/send-sms-c-net), Codygman gave an answer that some operators offer a way to send an SMS by sending an email to phonenumber@operator.com. I am curious about the technical solution behind that. I doubt they have a mailbox for every phone number.

Is there anyone out there who has a clue how they do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email on the internet operates on the [SMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). Standard MTAs (mail transport agents) will deliver messages to static mailboxes.

All the above solution requires is a custom MTA that instead of delivering to static mailboxes it interprets the username part of the address as a phone number and then pipes the request to an SMS gateway.

Certain mail software *might* be configurable enough such that this won't even require custom software and can be done with straight configuration.