# SMS Notifications in .NET

Tags: .net, sms

I'd like to send users on my site SMS notifications to their email in my .NET web application.  What services are available that will allow me to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548911/sending-sms and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380066/send-sms-c-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out [intelliSMS](http://www.intellisms.co.uk/sms-gateway/dotnet-component/) .NET component