# Sending sms and ussd in a C#.net application

Tags: c#, .net, sms, ussd

What is a good library to use to utilize sms and ussd services in a C#.net application?

Comment: Is it for a console or a windows forms application ?

Comment: So it's going to be more like an SMS Gateway. Take a look here [link](http://www.developershome.com/sms/), it suggests this [link](http://www.kannel.org/) for SMS Gateways

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS Library in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195624/sms-library-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using this one http://www.smsco.it/tomcat/en/sms_tutorials/sms_from_c_sharp.jsp for SMS and it's working fine!

Answer (score 2):

MessagingToolkit is supposed to be good. I've never used it myself though, so I can't vouch for it.

You can find out more at http://platform.twit88.com.