# Send a cellphone SMS text without the use of a third-party service

Tags: c#, php, .net, sms, windows-server-2008

Is it possible using a Windows Server, .NET, C# or PHP to send a SMS text message to q customer's cell phone without depending upon a third-party service (excluding an API provided by a phone company).

My require is to use SMS text messaging to automate authentication when resetting a customer's password, and I have security issues were I'd rather not use a third-party. The more I can keep this internal to our project the better (unless you can justify security in your answer).

**UPDATE:**

We've decided to use a SMS relay app and this was so easy to implement. There are many apps that already do this. Here is one I'm going to try.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS Library in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195624/sms-library-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build a simple mobile app that can query your api and send messages directly from the phone its running on. simple, cheap and you're in control!

we have this solution in a project Im working on atm and it seems to work great. Look up  http request and using sms/send message. At least on Android this can be done with just a handful of lines of code :)

Comment: oh very clever approach as we have multiple administrators with android phones.

Comment: And where exactly is the specific solution? I'm a bit confused why this is the accepted answer?

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos he wanted to send SMS messages from their internal systems, making a mobile app that sends SMS messages solves the problem - does it not?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a library like SMSLib:
http://smslib.org/

You will need to purchase a device that SMSLib can work with

Answer (score 0):

To the answers posted by others I would add the following:

- use [Gammu (or Wammu)](http://wammu.eu/gammu/): attach a phone or gsm modem with usb to your computer and send sms messages using Gammu. Pros: cheap solution, proven by users. Cons: work need to be done with installation and setup of Gammu/Wammu
- use a device called: hardware sms gateway (see [google search results](https://www.google.pl/search?q=hardware%2bsms%2bgateway) for possible examples). Pros:  reliability and security (those devices has usually built-in database, fail-over mechanisms, etc.). Cons: this costs money, so you've got to make investment.