# Can we send mail to mobile email address with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to send mail using CakePHP component to the following email ID: "999999999999@txt.att.net".

This email ID is of one mobile number! If I send mail to "999999999999@txt.att.net" it will come to his mobile message inbox! is it possible to do? Do I need to integrate any API for it? Please help me!

Comment: Please take care when posting questions that they’re readable and formatted correctly.

Comment: @martin Bean was doing it, suddenly post got submitted, i am editing it.

Comment: No need, I’ve already edited it for you ;)

Comment: @FDL thanks that was use full link..!!

Comment: This question, as it is now, is pretty confusing. Unlike other services (such as instant messaging) the mechanism to send e-mail is exactly the same no matter the recipient (thank God). Whatever the recipient decides to do with the message is an entirely different issue.

Comment: I asked this question before, and got some good answers but can't find my question. Can you search questions by poster?

Comment: @ alvaro G vicarion : I completely agree with you, but the point is we use email template while sending mail through CakePHP component, how does that template supports in message inbox.!!

Comment: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674409/send-a-cellphone-sms-text-without-the-use-of-a-third-party-service

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke if it's helpful. Upvote it. I need the points! :)

Comment: check this out: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en

Comment: @Mathew Are you using this app ?? does it help me for testing..?

Comment: I'm playing with it, but it doesn't work the way that I want. I might write my own since I do Android stuff already. There are a lot of SMS gateways in the play store. Try a few to see if they do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This does work for some mobile carriers, but the customer must activate the service. Allowing their phone to receive SMS texts via email. By default, carriers have this feature disabled.

So you would be required to have someone sign into their online account with their carrier, find this feature and enable it.

Something I don't think most people are even capable of doing.

Comment: Not only this, but carriers can and often do block inbound messages if they're sent from programs.

Comment: @somedev I just tested this, and Rogers sent my phone a message saying that I received an email text message. I would have to `subscribe` to an extra service to have the email sent to my phone. It's as I thought. It has to be enabled, and it'll likely cost people $$$ for the service.

Comment: @somedev : what is  block inbound messages ? can you please tell me.!

Comment: Indeed, just saying, we used to do this and had to stop because even if they signed up the carrier eventually blocked us. Each user was sent one message a week or so; but they didn't like us sending to hundreds of different users so ATT and Verizon would block the messages and treat them as spam.

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke I think he's just referring to general spam filtering, and since the carrier is the one doing the filter there is little you can do to stop it from being filtered.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini .. got it..!