# how to send SMS/Email from an application

Tags: iphone, email, sms

first of all thanks a lot to all of you for past valuable suggestions,we are creating an application where on certain events wants to send email/sms to specified phone number we already tried with the openURL call but it opens the existing inbuilt email/sms application of the iphone.Our requirement is to send sms/email without opening the inbuilt iphone email/sms application is it possible if yes what are the supported API's to achieve it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: From a native app or a web app?

Comment: You may want to tag this with iphone (assuming I am reading this correctly and that is the platform you are targeting) or update the title, as currently it is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [short code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) by way of a SMS/MMS aggregator like [OpenMarket](http://openmarket.com/) or as another person has posted you can use the [SMS Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) but this requires the knowledge of the end users carrier name. If your replying to a SMS on the iPhone I believe you can use the API which in turn would give you the carrier id of the incoming SMS message you would like to reply to.

Maybe you could explain your problem a little more so we can better grasp your question.

Comment: my problem is that by using the openURL API of iphone sdk we can open the emailmail.app or sms.app of the iphone from there if we click on send or cancel button it will send email or sms to the number specified ,but actually what we are looking for is to send the sms.email directly from our application without opening these in built email/sms.app applications of the iphone is it possible?please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: The only way I can see (If you don't have the carrier information upfront) is to use a Short Code as I have listed above, through a mobile messaging aggregator like www.openmarket.com

Comment: using a short code with an aggregator you can do number lookups (to see what carrier the number is) and send a custom SMS message with your application.

Comment: I don't get how this has *anything* to do with short codes!  Short codes are configured on the receiving side, whereas the poster asked about *sending* short messages.

Comment: @paprika the sender is asking how to send a SMS/MMS message to a phone. As far as I know there are only two ways, either email gateway or short code. You can send a message from phone to phone but the carrier does all the behind the scenes functionality like, number look up for carrier, routing, etc... what would you do?

Comment: @Phill Pafford: Sure, at some point the recipient's carrier is involved no matter what.  And this is the place where it matters whether or not the phone number is a short code or not (short codes are basically just short phone numbers, the service behind these phone numbers is a whole different issue).  Anyway, my point is that the poster is not concerned with the receiving side but rather the originating side, for which there is no technical difference between sending a message to a "normal" number and sending to a short code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125332/sms-from-our-site/1125369#1125369) from a similar question. Basically you can send an email to the phone if you know the provider. The provider will then format the email into a SMS message.