# Tack scheduler in asp.ner c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I M developing SMS Sending Website in Asp.net c#
I M Implementing SMS Scheduler where user schedule sms to be sent on specific Date and time.
i dont know how to implement it.
if anyone help me with process it will be better for me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125332/sms-from-our-site

Comment: So you expect us to do weeks of works for you free of charge base on a 3 line spec?

Answer (score 3):

I would write a special windows service to do this. If I were the designer I would have the web application sending an MSMQ message when a SMS request is collected. The service would read this queue and store in a local DB the request with the request time. Another thread would poll the event table to check the event to send at a certain time, and actually perform the sending. You possibly would to use a Transactional Queue and perform the DB event collection in a single transaction to ensure you really get the sending "mission".