# How to send SMS from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sms from our site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125332/sms-from-our-site)

I want to send SMS from my asp.net application. Suppose there will be 2 text boxes in my UI, one for mobile or cell phone number and another one is for message writing. When I will click the submit button then this SMS will be send to that cell number.
I want to use my cell phone number as transmission number. 
Please inform me the possible ways. 
I am using asp.net C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125332/sms-from-our-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a gateway or such kind of service first. The service provider will probably offer you the method or API to integrate your web site to their service. This topic has also been discussed in these forums for several times before. You can search for those threads and see if they are suitable for you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find yourself an SMS gateway and use their API.

Check out http://www.twilio.com/ they give you some free credit for when you sign up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several services which offer this kind of SMS Gateway API.

http://www.fastsms.co.uk/solutions/developer-api/developer-api.html
http://www.esendex.co.uk/Services/SMS-API

Or just search for "SMS Gateway API" for load more

Answer (score 1):

use "AT command"

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Sending_SMS_using_Net.aspx 
>   http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/